# Can there be any representation of a finite group which is reducible but indecomposable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, representation-theory, examples-counterexamples

> Can there be any representation of a finite group which is reducible but indecomposable?

I know that it is true that irreducibility implies indecomposability. But the converse is not necessarily true. For instance we could take $\Bbb Z$ and the representation $\varphi_n = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ which is not irreducible but indecomposable. Is there any analogous example for the representation of finite groups? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an explicit example in prime characteristic $p$, let the cyclic group of order $p$ act by powers of $(x,y)\mapsto (x,x+y)$ in dimension 2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are analogues in finite characteristic -- the same as your example for $n=1$ if the group is cyclic of order $m$, and $m \bmod p=0$.
In characteristic zero, irreducibility for finite group representations is equivalent to indecomposability. This is due to Maschke's theorem, see for example
[Understanding Maschke's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1653531/understanding-maschkes-theorem)